# Extract multiple URL of Text from MySQL column

Tags: mysql, sql

I'd like to extract certain snippets from a MySQL column which are bounded in some unique way. Here is an example:

I have the following column (Text):

```
| text
+---------
| lorem ipsum <a href="http://www.google.com/"rel="nofollow">http://www.google.com/</a>. Lorem ipsum. <a href="https://www.msn.com/" rel="nofollow">https://www.msn.com/</a>.

| lorem ipsum <a href="http://www.yahoo.com/" rel="nofollow">http://www.yahoo.com/</a>. Lorem ipsum. <a href="https://www.facebook.com/" rel="nofollow">https://www.facebook.com/</a>.
```

And I want to get this:

```
| result
+---------
| http://www.google.com/, https://www.msn.com/
| http://www.yahoo.com/, https://www.facebook.com/
```

Currently, I have this

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(
             SUBSTRING_INDEX(text, '">', -1 - n.v)
           , '</a>', 1) AS result
FROM   Test JOIN (
         SELECT 0 v
       UNION ALL
         SELECT 3
       ) n
```

But it is returning 2 rows. I need them in 1 row concatenated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The original data you are processing, that is on 2 row is it not?

Comment: Each row has text that contain at least 2 URLs. and sometimes more.

I want to the output as URLs only separated by comma.

Comment: [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)