# How to find all instances of URLs with a particular domain in a freetext field in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL DB, and a free text field which has a bunch of free text, and potentially URLs in it.

I would like to be able to find URLs that start with "https://hotspot.com", get the full URL, and any instances within the content. For example if we have 3 urls in the same field, I would like to get all 3 of them.

The table would look like:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sample` (
  `id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `content` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
INSERT INTO `sample` (`id`, `content`) VALUES
  ('1', 'chimichangas and stuff https://hotspot.com/files/filename.pdf'),
  ('2', 'One hundred angels can dance on the head of a pin'),
  ('3', 'The last unihorn https://hotspot.com/files/anotherfile.pdf and its so cool https://hotspot.com/files/morefile.png'),
  ('4', 'The earth is like a ball. https://yahoo.com/files/filename/pdf');
```

And I would like to get something like

1, https://hotspot.com/files/filename.pdf

3, https://hotspot.com/files/anotherfile.pdf

3, https://hotspot.com/files/morefile.png

(The id of the content, and the URLs it found in it. Although the format does not matter much as long as I get the info)
I was trying to get it with substring_index following some examples I found. But I am not sure I understand them. For example: [Extract multiple URL of Text from MySQL column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58628165/extract-multiple-url-of-text-from-mysql-column)

Comment: you might want to use regex for this

Comment: Yeah I thought about it, just curious if it can be done in MySQL.

Comment: mysql support regex, see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html

Comment: @Kristian I think this should work but returns 0 results? SELECT id, REGEXP_SUBSTR(content, "(https?:\/\/(.+?\.)?hotspot\.com(\/[A-Za-z0-9\-\._~:\/\?#\[\]@!$&'\(\)\*\+,;\=]*)?)") as cont  FROM sample;    I tested the patterns in regex and the expression works, but the query doesnt

Comment: And this returns only "hotspot.com/file" for some reason, instead of the entire string up to pdf 
SELECT id,  REGEXP_SUBSTR(content, "hotspot\.com([^\s]+)", 1) as cont  FROM sample;

Comment: I am also not sure how would I get multiple URLS from the same field using this?

Comment: please edit your question to include your attempt at REGEXP_SUBSTR

Answer (score 0):

Your attempt at REGEXP_SUBSTR works. I don't know why it returns 0 rows, but here's my working example, I just take yours and change a little:

```
SELECT
REGEXP_SUBSTR(content,'(https?:\/\/([A-Za-z0-9]+?\.)?hotspot\.com(\/[A-Za-z0-9\-\._~:\/\?#[@\]!$&()*\+,;\=]*)?)',1,1),
REGEXP_SUBSTR(content,'(https?:\/\/([A-Za-z0-9]+?\.)?hotspot\.com(\/[A-Za-z0-9\-\._~:\/\?#[@\]!$&()*\+,;\=]*)?)',1,2),
REGEXP_SUBSTR(content,'(https?:\/\/([A-Za-z0-9]+?\.)?hotspot\.com(\/[A-Za-z0-9\-\._~:\/\?#[@\]!$&()*\+,;\=]*)?)',1,3),
REGEXP_SUBSTR(content,'(https?:\/\/([A-Za-z0-9]+?\.)?hotspot\.com(\/[A-Za-z0-9\-\._~:\/\?#[@\]!$&()*\+,;\=]*)?)',1,4)
FROM sample
```

Result:

| col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| https://hotspot.com/files/filename.pdf | NULL | NULL NULL |  |
| NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| https://hotspot.com/files/anotherfile.pdf | https://hotspot.com/files/morefile.png | NULL | NULL |
| NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |

#### Explanation:

REGEXP_SUBSTR arguments are

- string to be matched
- regex pattern
- starting index
- index of occurrence

by selecting 1-4 index of occurrence we can capture up to 4 url in a single row

If you expect there is more, you can just add more columns

#### What I changed:

before:

`(https?:\/\/(.+?\.)?hotspot\.com(\/[A-Za-z0-9\-\._~:\/\?#[]@!$&'()*\+,;\=]*)?)`

after:

`(https?:\/\/([A-Za-z0-9]+?\.)?hotspot\.com(\/[A-Za-z0-9\-\._~:\/\?#[@\]!$&()*\+,;\=]*)?)`

I just changed your `(.+?\.)?` into `([A-Za-z0-9]+?\.)?` to prevent greedy matching all when there's multiple url in one string (I guess this capture group is for matching subdomains of hotspot.com)